# Why am I getting the error "cannot open file 'msvcprtd.lib'" when I try to run my react-native-windows app from vs code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, window, react-native-windows

I set up a react native windows app following these set up instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/react-native-for-windows. I've installed all of the dependencies and checked that they're installed by running this command in an elevated powershell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force;
iex (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://aka.ms/rnw-vs2022-deps.ps1');
```

Here is my output
[image]

But when I run

```
npx react-native run-windows
```

in my VS Code terminal at the root of the project, I keep getting this error

`Build failed with message 7:7>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprtd.lib' [C:\Users\SarahCarter\Documents\Apps\test\node_modules\react-native-windows\Microsoft.ReactNative\Microsoft.ReactNative.vcxproj]. Check your build configuration.`

I get the same error when I follow the directions to run my app from Visual Studio. I didn't make any changes to the app after following the get started instructions, so it must be an issue with the set up.

Also of note, I have Windows Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621, which is compatible with react native windows according to the system requirements here https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/rnw-dependencies

What is the msvcprtd.lib file and how do I fix this error?

Thanks in advance!